# Call tomcat server war url from external html page using ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, tomcat

I am using **apache-tomcat-7.0.67** with a deployed jar under `webapps` folder War name ::

```
Account
```

The war has been created using spring-boot so there is no web.xml explicitly defined , but the url mapping has been defined using `@RequestMapping(value="/submitForm",method = RequestMethod.POST)`
When i hit this url from **Postman** or **JMeter** like `http://localhost:8080/Account/submitForm` the request reaches the server and response is returned. 
 Now i have another folder which just contains html files which are not in war like
[image]

it has some html files which contains **ajax** calls using javascript like

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Account/submitForm',
                 success: function (resp) {
                 console.log(resp);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                console.log('Error: ',e);
                }  
            });
```

But the request never reaches the server even after using url: `'https://localhost:8080/Account/submitForm'` , Can anyone please let me know how to solve this i am completely stuck.

Comment: How do you know the request "never reaches the server"? Having the files in `webapps/html` means they are being served from a servlet context ("web app") from the `/Account` context.

Comment: I came to know that from **Net** panel of Firebug where it shows status `Aborted` , sorry i didn't get as you said `means they are being served from a servlet context ("web app") from the /Account context` please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is javascripts cross-domain origin policy which is not allowing any ajax call from static html file outside my war file. I resolved that by adding

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>`
```

in tomcat's `web.xml` file which allows cross domain origin calls. Also spring gives its support for cross origin as i found in a good link here [cors-support-in-spring-framework](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)
 Here is the specification from W3C [W3 cors specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should not use the name of your war

I use here such request

```
$.ajax( ... url: "../GUI/ResponseTime", ...
```

And this annotation in my class

```
@WebServlet(name = "ResponseTime", urlPatterns = {"/GUI/ResponseTime"})
```

it works regardless of the war name of the file

Comment: No it will map by the context name , the actual problem is with the cross-domain (CORS) policy of javascript, it is not allowing any url call from html file outside my war. Anyways thanks for your suggestion